# How to perform a segue that is on a UITabBarController from a sub view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a UITabBarController that has a segue that leads to my login view.  When a user is looking at one of the subviews, the user can press a log out button that should bring up the login view.  How can I access the segue from my UITabBarController inside of my sub view which is a UITableViewController

Comment: You probably shouldn't use a segue for this purpose. Just present the login view modally from any controller that has this button.

Answer (score 0):

@rdelmar is awfully smart, so take his/her caution seriously.  However, it seems to me that:

```
[[self tabBarController] performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:self];
```

...ought to work from any view controller contained by the tab bar controller.